# How would I add search bar to off canvas menu?

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, searchbar

Hi how would I be able to add a search bar to an off canvas menu that doesn't close the menu when the searchbar is clicked on?

Comment: Hi do you have some code you can provide? That really helps others to understand what you want to do / allows them to provide constructive answers. Thanks :)

Comment: Look this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

(Next time you can show us your code so we can edit your code)

I have an example here from @W3Schools. Maybe it will help you.

@W3Schools
[Click to open their website](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_off-canvas.asp)

You can replace the `<a href="#">Example</a>` with `<a href="#"><input type="text"></a>`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 16px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#"><input type="search" placeholder="Search"></a>
</div>

<div id="main">
  <h2>Sidenav Push Example</h2>
  <p>Click on the element below to open the side navigation menu, and push this content to the right.</p>
  <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
</div>

<script>
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
}
</script>
   
</body>
</html>
```

**Happy Coding!**

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue as OP and this is my code:

```
<div class="offcanvas offcanvas-end" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvasRight" aria-labelledby="offcanvasRightLabel">
  <div class="offcanvas-header">
    <h5 class="offcanvas-title" id="offcanvasRightLabel">offcanvas</h5>
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
  </div>
  <div class="offcanvas-body">

        <form class="d-flex" role="search" method="get">
          <input class="form-control me-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" name="search" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['search'])){echo $_GET['']; }?>" >
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit" name="button">Search</button>
        </form>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33327132)